# IIS 7.5 fails to open database after computer machine on that database server is working restarts

Tags: sql-server

I decided to post this question also here in case the issues we have is related to sql server.

There is a problem that bother me for some time. I have an asp.net mvc that uses NHibernate for modeling the database. The infrastructure is the following: Windows 2008 R2 for all virtual machines. IIS 7.5 is working on one virtual machine. Sql Server 2008 is working on another virtual machine. We have couple of databases, two that stores application data and one that registers all unhandled exceptions.

Sometimes virtual machine that hosts database server restarts (in the middle of the night, not quite sure about the reason) after that connection to the databases that stores application data is not working and as result there are thousands of unhandled exceptions that get registered in the third database. Important to mention that databases are accessible from Management Studio. The problem is solved by resetting IIS. Connetion are handled via NHibernateUtil class which opens and closes session at each request.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like a coding error to me. Basically - yes, the app is not usable while sql server restarts. Happens (look into a second server running a mirror if you fix that).

If the web app though gets permanently unusable something is bad with the handling of database connections. Like the app "holding on" to unusable database connections, instead of letting them go and just open new ones. Breaking best practices (keep db connections only open as lnog as needed).

The reason for sql server restart may be patching, btw., CHeck auto update settings.